# C++ get Index value in integer from iterator

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, indexing, iterator

I am trying to get the index value from iterator. But I keep getting the error "Indirection requires pointer operand ('long' invalid)"
Any idea? I need to get the index. on the following example, it should output 2.

```
template<typename T>
void practice(T begin, T end) {
    T it = begin;
    it++;
    it++;
    auto index = it - begin;
    cout << *index;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to dereference an index (which is inherently integral)? And since you accept any type of iterator, use `std::distance`. I would suggest doing that even if you didn't in case it changes later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout << index;
```

No need for the `*` dereference.